# Reusing the consumed characters in pattern matching in java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Consider the following Pattern :-

```
aba
```

And the foll. source string :-

```
abababbbaba

01234567890    //Index Positions
```

Using Pattern and Matcher classes from java.util.regex package, finds this pattern only two times since regex does not consider already consumed characters.

What if I want to reuse a part of already consumed characters. That is, I want 3 matches here, one at position 0, one at 2 (which is ignored previously), and one at 8.

How do I do it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)() for something like that.

```
String str = "abababbbaba";
        String substr = "aba";
        int location = 0;
        while ((location = str.indexOf(substr, location)) >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println(location);
            location++;
        }
```

Prints:

0, 2 and 8

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that. Now what you have is the first position in `group(1)` and the second match in `group(2)`. Both making each String of length 3 in the sentence you are searching in.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Question8968432 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String needle = "aba";
        final String sentence = "abababbbaba";
        final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.)(?=(..))").matcher(sentence);
        while (m.find()) {
            final String match = m.group(1) + m.group(2);
            final String hint = String.format("%s[%s]%s",
                sentence.substring(0, m.start()), match, 
                sentence.substring(m.start() + match.length()));
            if (match.equals(needle)) {
                System.out.printf("Found %s starting at %d: %s\n", 
                    match, m.start(), hint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found aba starting at 0: [aba]babbbaba
Found aba starting at 2: ab[aba]bbbaba
Found aba starting at 8: abababbb[aba]
```

You can skip the `final String hint` part, this is just to show you what it matches and where.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the regexp, then you can simply use something like:

```
a(?=ba)
```